# Get SharePoint online list name from GUID in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

Why am I getting this error when I run the code below?

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException: 'The property or field 'Title' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.'

```
 public  string getInternalNameOfList(string siteURL, Guid listGUID)
    {
        string listName = "";
        ClientContext clientContextD = new ClientContext(siteURL);
        clientContextD.Credentials = _credentials;
        ListCollection listCollectionD = clientContextD.Web.Lists;

        clientContextD.Load(listCollectionD, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Id , list => list.Title, list => list.SchemaXml, list => list.TemplateFeatureId, list => list.Fields));
        clientContextD.ExecuteQuery();

        Web oWebsiteD = clientContextD.Web;

        clientContextD.ExecuteQuery();
        listName = clientContextD.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetById(listGUID).Title;
        return listName;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code to the below:

```
List list = web.Lists.GetById(listGUID);
clientContextD.Load(list);
clientContextD.ExecuteQuery();
listName = list.Title
```